# Como usar Select

Tags: android, sqlite, crud

Consegui salvar informações no meu banco do SQLite, só que não consigo chamar elas.

Estou tentando usando o seguinte método:

```
private void verPessoas() {
    ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> pessoas = new Read().getLista();
    for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++) {
        RespostasAguaCasa p = pessoas.get(i);
        int a = p.getValoragua();
        impri.setText("+"+ a);
    }

    if (pessoas.size() == 0) System.out.println("# Não existe valor .");
}
```

READ

```
      public class Read {
            public ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> getLista() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = 
          Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Maindb.TABELA;
            ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    RespostasAguaCasa resp = new 
                   RespostasAguaCasa(c.getString(0));
                    resp.setId(c.getInt(1));
                    resp.setValoragua(c.getInt(2));
                    resp.setAcordarhora(c.getInt(3));
                    resp.setAcordarminu(c.getInt(4));
                    resp.setDormirhora(c.getInt(5));
                    resp.setDormirminu(c.getInt(6));
                    lista.add(resp);
                }
                while (c.moveToNext());
                {
                }


    }
    c.close();
    return lista;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - É necessário começar a Tabela Pessoas com um valor?

No caso de ( Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(c.getString(0)); )
deixamos um construtor vazio para a Tabela, de modo que possamos chamar assim:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
pessoa.setNome("nome");
```

2 - Chame os resultados pelas colunas:

```
pessoa.setNome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Coluna_Nome)));
```

3 - No Caso de ( pessoa.setDeficiencia(c.getInt(4) == 1); )
seria melhor algo do tipo:

```
Int valor_temporario = 0;
if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Tabela_Deficiencia)) == 1){
valor_temporario = 1;
}else{
valor_temporario = 0;
}
pessoa.setDeficiencia(valor_temporario);
```

De Resto parece OK, caso não for nada desse tipo, precisaria de mais informações.

Comment: estou tendo problemas em chamar o c

Comment: Tinha pegado o Read do projeto errado se poder me ajudar com o certo editei a pergunta